# Why HOVER on image behind the the normal image?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have a problem with hover. I have a normal pic with opacity and another one with white background. I did this:

html:

```
<div id="glob" style="margin-right:5px;margin-top:2px;float:right;height:45px;width:40px;">
<img src="images/icon_globus.png" width="32" height="33" alt="" style="margin-right:5px;margin-top:7px;"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
  #glob:hover{

   background:url('../images/icon_globushover.png') no-repeat;

  }
```

As you can see from the pic, the white one (upper globus) is behind the other one. It should not be behind.

What is not good?

---

**EDIT:** Thanks all, it's working. I did like the first answer. Don't know why I used img tag. I always use divs as image, but here I was stupid. **Thanks a lot all for your help!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because background always has the lowest z-index of all elements and content will be on top of it. I would suggest you to put "images/icon_globus.png" this as a background for div glob and remove that image tag. Then it should work the way you want it.

Comment: ok thanks i going to try! one moment EDIT: working what a stupid am i :)... thanks

Answer (score 0):

try without the image part.

```
glob {
    background: url('icon_globus.png');
}
glob:hover {
    background: url('icon_globus_hover.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all style and change as below

// CSS

```
glob:hover{background: url("/images/icon_globushover.png") no-repeat;}
.glob{
background: url("/images/icon_globus.png") no-repeat;
float: right;
margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0px;
width: 32px;
height: 33px;
}


<div class="glob"></div>
```

if your path source is like this

myhardrive/MysiteFolder/Images/ and your index.html is in MysiteFolder so in css must be `(/images/)`

if your path source is like this

myhardrive/MysiteFolder/files/mystyle.css here you do `("..\images\")`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers you want to support, you could do something like this in CSS:

```
#glob { position: relative; }
#glob:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background:url('../images/icon_globushover.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your image icon_globus.png is above your div background so when you hover, you actually apply a background to the container containing your image, you globushover appears behind your  ..

try this instead:
html:

```
<div id="glob></div>
```

css:

```
#glob {margin-right:5px;margin-top:2px;float:right;height:45px;width:40px;background:url('../images/icon_globus.png') no-repeat;}
#glob:hover{
   background:url('../images/icon_globushover.png') no-repeat;
  }
```

this way you change/overwrite the default background-image. css means cascade style, cascade is wat permits you to overwrite styles depending on a certain condition, thats theory applied here. just overwrite a background-image with another one on hover.